# Flask Server for Listening to HTTP Responses

Tags: python, flask

I am working on making a Flask server that can listen to a node that would like to contact the server at any point of time and then the flask server process the response. I would like to ask whether there's any method to listen to the connection attempted by the remote node.

Answer (score 0):

Flask has a development server, documented [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/server/#server):

```py
FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run
```

Note that the server is not intended for production. If you're looking for production server, you can read [this page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/#deployment). There are several solutions, such as [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/), [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and more.